# Exit code -1 when uploading image ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When i want to pick image to upload, server stops with exit code -1.

I created default application ASP.NET Core MVC.

Edited Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SingleFile"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Edited HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();  
        }

        public IActionResult SingleFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            //breakpoint here
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Application runs perfect. But when i click "Open File" it opens File Dialog, then i pick image (even close file dialog) application crashes with exit code -1. Breakpoint in HomeController.cs never reaches, because application crushes before. I tested a lot of tutorials, but the same

Console output

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2

C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\bin\Debug\net5.0\WebApplication2.exe (процесс 15128) завершил работу с кодом -1.
```

UPD:
even if i leave html code (delete asp-... tags and @)

Updated index.cshtml

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form>
        <input type="file"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Application behaves the same

Comment: seems something is missing or not correctly implemented... do yourself a favor and follow [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to see what's missing.

Comment: @balexandre, thanks for answer, i updated post and application doesn't work correctly with only html code

Comment: if you see the documentation I linked, you see that for uploading files, the form must be always set with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, you can't upload files in any other way... please follow the tutorial in a new project, you will not only learn new things, but also learn how to fix things by your own and not need to wait for anyone else do things for you 

Comment: You have error 15128.  See : https://mindovermessaging.com/2014/08/21/gotchas-when-accessing-an-iaas-sql-server-in-an-azure-cloud-service/

Answer (score 0):

- Add method="post" to the form
- Add [HttpPost] for controller action

Answer (score 0):

Running your application via CTRL+F5 without debugger